# How can I connect my database of Wordpress with lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am not able to solve a problem:

1. I want to run a python script which is scraping information from the web according to an input.
2. This input will come from Wordpress (Either from the frontend or database of Wordpress)
3. After getting input from, I figured out that AWS Lambda can do the scraping automatically.

Now the problem is, how can I connect my database of Wordpress with Lambda. API Getaway would get information from that Wordpress frontend, save it in DynamoDB and Lambda could then run the Python code. BUT, the input is user specific. So the user should be able to change that input when he wants it.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect my database of Wordpress with Lambda"? Can you please edit your Question and include a description of the end-to-end process you wish to implement?

Comment: Well, I want to run my python code with the inputs that have been collected from Wordpress and are in the Wordpress Database.

Comment: You an trigger an AWS Lambda function directly via an API call, or via API Gateway, Amazon SQS, Amazon SNS, object creation in Amazon S3, [data change in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) (might be relevant for you) and probably other ways I can't remember.

Comment: @CodeCodeNoob Did you ever resolve this?  I want to do the same thing (Have an AWS Lambda function write data to WP database).  With my client I can not connect directly; rather a ssh connection is required.  So I assume I must do the same to have lambda function connect to WP db.